# Creating ZIP file in Memory and sending via POST request

Tags: python, python-requests, stringio

I am attempting to create a zip file in memory with python that I will then attach to a POST request to send with python-requests. Here is the function I wrote

```
import StringIO,zipfile
code = "poopootest"
def _build_zip_inmem(code):
    mf = StringIO.StringIO()
    with zipfile.ZipFile(mf, mode='w', compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zf:
        zf.writestr('../../../../../../../../../var/www/html/ATutor/mods/poc/1111.phtml', code)
        zf.writestr('imsmanifest.xml', "noxmlhereoops")
    mf.write(zf)
    print mf.getvalue()
    return mf.getvalue()
_build_zip_inmem(code)
```

This basically works except getvalue() seems to also return the memory address of the object.  The ending output of the print line says `<zipfile.ZipFile object at 0x7f4e8ba434d0>` and I believe this is why my POST is failing.

How do I convert this in-memory zip to binary that can then be sent via POST?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mf.getvalue()` ends with `<zipfile.ZipFile object at 0x7f4e8ba434d0>` because you wrote that string to `mf` when you called `mf.write(zf)`.  This call to `write()` is unnecessary, as the zipfile was already written to `mf` by the `with zipfile.ZipFile(mf, ...)` block.